# How to get a value from CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I am using next code to execute fetch request -

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TimerEntity")
let managedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

do {
  let result = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
  if result.count > 0 {
    print(result)
}
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

But, when I print it, I get this in debug area -

```
[{
    first = 0;
    second = 3657;
    third = 0;
    fourth = 0;
}, {
    first = 0;
    second = 0;
    third = 0;
    fourth = 653;
}]
```

Before I set a value for fourth key, I've got only first part of printed in logs.
What am I doing wrong? I need only one JSON to work with it

UPD1...

I think that when I setValue for the next attribute - it creates new json. But why? All of these attributes in the same entity.

UPD2...

Code of setting a value

```
 let managedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
 let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TimerEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
 let timerEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

 timerEntity.setValue(seconds+(minutes*60)+(hours*3600), forKey: "second")

 do {
   try managedObjectContext.save()
 } catch let error as NSError {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

Comment: Is it a do while loop? Looks incomplete.

Comment: @Bhumit I showed just a beginning. It's a do { } catch { }

Comment: If you only need one result in your query set `fetchLimit` to 1 on the request. Select the object you want to query using a predicate on the same request.

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is clear from what you wrote.  What is the issue you are dealing with?

Comment: @JorisKluivers I need to show changes in the same json, not in the next. For example, if I will set new value for second attribute and I already have value in first - I need to show them in the same json

Comment: @bolnad read my previous comment, please

Comment: @EgorKuznetsov can you show your code for how you are setting the values on the entity?

Comment: @bolnad yes, of course. I updated my post

Comment: @EgorKuznetsov glad someone was able to help u! sorry i couldn't sooner

Comment: @bolnad don't keep in mind, you tried, thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted to update the entity property you are not updating an existing object, you are creating a new object using `NSManagedObject(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)`.

You might be confusing the `entityName` for the fetch request for an object id, which it is not. It refers to the object type. If you want to keep track of a single object of that type you should probably add an identifier property to the object (something like `timerID`) or use the `NSManagedObject`'s `objectID`.

Comment: oh, thanks you, @JorisKluivers ! You saved a lot of my time!

Comment: I know that I am asking for a lot, but could you give me an example of updating an existing value?

Comment: When saving your first object, set a unique identifier on the object: `timer.setValue(NSUUID().UUIDString, forKey: "timerID")`. Then query for the object with a predicate on your fetch request: `NSPredicate(format: "timerID == %@", timerID)`

Comment: Though I wouldn't recommend working directly with `NSManagedObject` and `setValue`. You could create managed object subclasses for your timer object. Look into `Editor -> Create NSManagedObject subclass`, so you can set properties with `timer.timerID = ....`

Comment: Thanks you! You are AWESOME!